Screen flickering with vertical lines
I have an external monitor, Samsung U32R59x, that starts to flicker with vertical lines under certain conditions. My computer is a Macbook Pro, 2022, with an M2-processor. MacOS was reinstalled once I got the computer, and the issue started immediately.
I have not figured out a pattern for the flickering, but it often happens when I browse certain pages in Mozilla Firefox. It also occurs when using other software. The same website in Firefox doesn't trigger the flickering every time.

﻿I recorded a video of the flickering.
I believe it is something software-related: I click onto a tab with black background, and the screen flickers, and as soon as I click into a tab with grey background, it stops.
This also happens if I focus away from a program, i.e. click on the background.
I have connected my Macbook to other screens, and have never experienced this.
I have used other computers on this particular screen and never experienced this.
Below is the graphics tab of System Report (sorry, in Danish)
Apple M2:

  Chipsæt-model:    Apple M2
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Indbygget
  Antal kerner i alt:   10
  Producent:    Apple (0x106b)
  Metal-understøttelse: Metal 3
  Skærme:
U32R59x:
  Opløsning:    3840 x 2160 (2160p/4K UHD 1 – Ultra High Definition)
  UI ligner:    3840 x 2160 @ 60.00Hz
  Hovedskærm:   Ja
  Dublering:    Fra
  Online:   Ja
  Rotation: Understøttet
LCD-farveskærm:
  Skærmtype:    Indbygget Retina LCD
  Opløsning:    2560 x 1600 Retina
  Dublering:    Fra
  Online:   Ja
  Juster lysstyrke automatisk:  Ja
  Tilslutningstype: Intern

Are there configuration options that allow me to get rid of the flickering?
I have tried different resolutions and cables.
